# Guacamole. Внутренняя ошибка сервера

Tags: linux, tomcat

Устанавливаю Apache Guacamole на Raspberry Pi (речь идет о Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 8 GB, операционная система Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye),  5.15.61-v7l+).

Делаю все в такой последовательности:

Обновляю репозиторий

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Устанавливаю пакеты

```
sudo apt install make libcairo2-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libtool-bin uuid-dev
```

Устанавливаю Apache Tomcat

```
sudo apt install tomcat9 tomcat9-admin tomcat9-common tomcat9-user

sudo systemctl start tomcat9
sudo systemctl enable tomcat9
```

Устанавливаю Guacamole

```
wget https://apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/guacamole/1.5.2/source/guacamole-server-1.5.2.tar.gz?action=download
tar -xvzf guacamole-server-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd guacamole-server-1.5.2
sudo ./configure --with-init-dir=/etc/init.d
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo systemctl enable guacd
```

Клиент

```
wget https://apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/guacamole/1.5.2/binary/guacamole-1.5.2.war?action=download
sudo mkdir /etc/guacamole
sudo mv guacamole-1.5.2.war /etc/guacamole/guacamole.war
sudo systemctl restart tomcat9
sudo systemctl restart guacd
```

Создаю /etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties со следующим содержимым:

```
guacd-hostname: localhost
guacd-port: 4822
user-mapping: /etc/guacamole/user-mapping.xml
```

```
sudo mkdir /etc/guacamole/{extensions,lib}
sudo sh -c "echo 'GUACAMOLE_HOME=/etc/guacamole' >> /etc/default/tomcat9"
```

Создаю /etc/guacamole/user-mapping.xml, в качестве IP указываю IP-адрес сервера...

```
<user-mapping>
    <authorize username="admin"
            password="36160e235d67eb081741004798ee37a8d"
            encoding="md5"> <connection name="Ubuntu20.04-Server">
            <protocol>ssh</protocol>
            <param name="hostname">192.168.1.2</param>
            <param name="port">22</param>
            <param name="username">root</param>
        </connection>
        <connection name="Windows Server">
            <protocol>rdp</protocol>
            <param name="hostname">192.168.2.3</param>
            <param name="port">3389</param>
        </connection>
    </authorize>
</user-mapping>
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

> Соединение было прервано из-за внутренней ошибки сервера Guacamole. Пожалуйста, попробуйте повторить попытку позднее или обратитесь к администратору.

Вот что видно в логах Tomcat-а

> [2023-07-03 14:28:55] [info] 14:28:55.975 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR o.a.g.s.GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet - HTTP tunnel request failed: java.net.ConnectException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt>

...т.е. соединение отклонено.

Что я делаю не так?